# Copiar Propriedade de Objeto em outro

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho 2 objectos:

```
var a = {
          "propriedade_um": "1",
          "propriedade_dois": "2"
        }

var b = {
          "propriedade_tres": "3",
          "propriedade_quatro": "4"
        }
```

Como eu faço para pegar a `propriedade_um` do objecto `a` e passar para que `b` fique assim:

```
var b = {
          "propriedade_tres": "3",
          "propriedade_quatro": "4",
          "propriedade_um": "1"
        }
```

Obrigado!!

Comment: Não seria apenas definir? `b.propriedade_um = a.propriedade_um`

Comment: Sim, perfeito! É isso mesmo :) Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = {
      "propriedade_um": "1",
      "propriedade_dois": "2"
    }

var b = {
      "propriedade_tres": "3",
      "propriedade_quatro": "4"
    }

b["propriedade_um"] = a.propriedade_um;
```

Comment: Obrigado Cara!!